# Bignum libraries for windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, encryption

Are there any bignum libraries that are good for Windows use? I looked at GMP, but unfortunately it does not look like it can be compiled on Windows...(I'm going to be doing some custom RSA and hashing routines)

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

People provide [pre-compiled binaries](ftp://deltatrinity.dyndns.org/gmp-4.3.1_DLL_SharedLibs/) for gmp on Windows; there are also [instructions](http://cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/gmp/) for compiling it yourself. Another option would be the [bignum library of OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/bn.html).

Answer (score 3):

Another option is [MPIR](http://mpir.org). MPIR is a fork of GMP that specifically support compilation on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.openssl.org/ is stable and time proven library.
It also includes well separable bignum libray

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at [MAPM, A Portable Arbitrary Precision Math Library in C.](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~ringx004/mapm-main.html) It also contains C++ wrappers.