# Arbitrary precision in c++ using Windows?

Tags: c++, numbers, arbitrary-precision

Is there a library that can be implemented relatively easily in windows?
I made a few functions a while ago which used arrays of numbers to get the desired outcome. I might work at them when I get the time.

But is there any such feature already available that can be implemented into c++ easily?

Comment: Related Question: [Bignum libraries for windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286578/bignum-libraries-for-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently people have had luck with using the [GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](http://gmplib.org/) [for Windows](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/gmp/).